# Three bases generating the same topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

> Consider the following three families of subsets of $\mathbb R^2$.
>
> Let $Σ^2$ consist of all possible open disks, $Σ^∞$ consist of all possible open square with sides parallel to the coordinate axis, and $Σ^1$ consist of all possible open square with sides parallel to the angle bisectors coordinate axis (i.e. ordinary square rotated 45 degrees).
>
> Prove that each of the collections $Σ^2, Σ^∞$ and $Σ^1$ is a base for some topological structure in $\mathbb R^2$, and that the structures determined by these collections coincide.

The textbook I'm referring to has very few examples, I'm having a hard time following it. Can anyone give me ideas for this exercise? I really have no idea.

Comment: You have to show that every element of $\Sigma^i$ can be written as an union of elements of $\Sigma^k$ with $i, k \in \{ 2,1, \infty \}$. In this way you show that the topology defined by $\Sigma^k$ is finer than the one defined by $\Sigma^i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** First of all, use the following result to show that the collections $\Sigma^1$, $\Sigma^2$, and $\Sigma^{\infty}$ are bases for topologies on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

> A collection $\Sigma$ of subsets of a set $X$ is a base for a certain topology on $X$ if and only if $X$ is the union of all sets in $\Sigma$ and the intersection of any two sets in $\Sigma$ is the union of some sets in $\Sigma$.

Then use the following to show they are all bases for the same topology (i.e. let $\tau$ be the topology generated by one of them, say $\Sigma^1$, then apply the result to $\Sigma^2$ and $\Sigma^{\infty}$).

> Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space. A collection $\Sigma$ of open sets is a base for $\tau$ if and only if for every open set $U$ and every point $x \in U$, there is a set $V \in \Sigma$ such that $x \in V$ and $V \subseteq U$.

You may find the following picture helpful.

$\hspace{6.4cm}$[image]